# Variadic template parameters from integer

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

Given I have that type

```
template<int ...Is>
struct A {};
```

Can I "generate" the type `A<0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,..., d>` just from an integer d?

I thought about something like

```
template<int d>
struct B : A<std::index_sequence<d>...> {}
```

but it doesn't work.

Other option is to specialize manually:

```
template<int d>
struct B;

template<>
struct B<0>: A<> {};

template<>
struct B<1>: A<0> {};

template<>
struct B<2>: A<0, 1> {};

template<>
struct B<3>: A<0, 1, 2> {};
```

but obviously I don't be able to write `B<3000> b;`

[edit] my actual use-case is a "bit" more complex than that. I don't want to reimplement std::integer_sequence, but something more complex.

Comment: What you want is `std::make_integer_sequence`.

Comment: @Evg can you elaborate please?

Comment: Your compiler will probably bail out at 3000 template parameters.

Comment: @n.m. If I'm right, there is a compiler setting for that :)

Comment: As a stupid lowly Python programmer - _why_ would one ever want to do this?

Comment: @AdamBarnes to make that : https://github.com/JeWaVe/euler/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We already have what you want in the Standard library - `std::make_integer_sequence`. If you want to use your own type `A<...>` you can do this:

```
template<int... Is>
struct A {};

template<class>
struct make_A_impl;

template<int... Is>
struct make_A_impl<std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>> {
    using Type = A<Is...>;
};

template<int size>
using make_A = typename make_A_impl<std::make_integer_sequence<int, size>>::Type;
```

And then for `A<0, ..., 2999>` write

```
make_A<3000>
```

Comment: So the `make_A_impl` declaration is needed to workaround the fact that you can't have two parameter packs in one template argument list?

Comment: @StackDanny, I didn't fully get your question. `make_A_impl` is used to "unpack" `std::integer_sequence` into `int...`.

Answer (score 4):

A bit another way to do - use function signature to match the `A<...>` type:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<int ...Is>
struct A {};

namespace details
{
template <int ...Is>
auto GenrateAHelper(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>) -> A<Is...>;
}

template<int I> 
using GenerateA = decltype(details::GenrateAHelper(std::make_integer_sequence<int, I>()));

static_assert(std::is_same<GenerateA<3>, A<0, 1, 2>>::value, "");
```